# gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1' on OS X 10.10 Yosemite not installing

Tags: ruby, macos, nokogiri, osx-yosemite

After update to OS X 10.10 Yosemite I can't install nokogiri (1.6.3.1)

```
> bundle

Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@sumup/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@sumup/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
> brew update
> brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv

> brew --prefix libxml2
/usr/local/opt/libxml2

> brew --prefix libxslt
/usr/local/opt/libxslt

> brew --prefix libiconv
/usr/local/opt/libiconv

> gem uninstall nokogiri

> gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.3.1 -- --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxslt --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config
```

Based on: [Mac fix 1 - Install the Nokogiri gem on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SteveBenner/de51738222e92d606487/raw/7cd7c552894b86895189189bd340bdc6e7f68ddb/macfix1-install-nokogiri.rb)

Other solution:

```
> gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.3.1 -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/
```

Another solution from comments:

```
> xcode-select --install gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I think the `--prefix` isn't needed (I have never used it) just brew install the binary libraries then do `gem install nokogiri`

Comment: I'm using it to get the right paths, for me it's needed

Comment: Worked for me in 10.10 Yosemite (without the xcode-select..)

Comment: Why is it only nokogiri failing everytime i update osx. So painful

Comment: What worked for me was the mentioned  `gem install nokogiri -v x.x.x -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/include/libxml2/`

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me on Yosemite 10.10.3:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries
```

It was taken from the [Nokogiri issues tracker](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1231).

Answer (score 1):

> brew update
>   brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv
>
> brew --prefix libxml2
>   /usr/local/opt/libxml2
>
> brew --prefix libxslt
>   /usr/local/opt/libxslt
>
> brew --prefix libiconv
>   /usr/local/opt/libiconv
>
> gem uninstall nokogiri
>
> gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.3.1 -- --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxslt --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/opt/libxslt/bin/xslt-config

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to install gems into local folder and get error

```
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Then, you need to do following to use

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Then install will pass with

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.6.3.1
Installing nokogiri 1.6.3.1 with native extensions
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
```